# Unable to import tkinter?

Tags: 12.04, python3

I am studying Python and tried to make GUI using python.I am using IDLE 3.2 on 12.04 Ubuntu.When i typed `import Tkinter`, a error comes, it says following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import Tkinter
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong and how I can resolve this?

Comment: I have already installed python3-tk.But the same error comes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the package `python3-tk`.

And in Python3 the module is called `tkinter` instead of `Tkinter`.

Comment: But i have already installed it?. i can't understand

Comment: @YomalSamindu: Are you sure you are using Python3? For Python2 you need `python-tk` instead.

Comment: yes i am pretty sure. its python 3.2

Comment: In Python3 the module is called `tkinter` instead of `Tkinter` (added that to my answer)

Comment: @YomalSamindu As a note, alot of capitalization has changed in tkinter between python2 and python3. Check your capitals first for any future problems

Comment: after i entered `import tkinter` it worked.THank you very much for your helps.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch please give me 1 up for my questions.Thank you!