# configure tkinter for python3.4.2

Tags: 14.04, python, package-management, tkinter

I recently met a problem while installing the newest python3.X.
Installed it using the `Python-3.4.2.tar.xz` package from `python.org`
After, the intallation I tried importing the `tkinter` module but didn't succeed.

The output of `import tkinter` was:

```
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in 
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I also tried following solutions:

- [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu),
- [second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513981/tkinter-on-ubuntu-14-04-seems-not-to-work),
- [third](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472854/tkinter-not-working),
- [fourth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355420/unable-to-import-tkinter) and
- [fifth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505141/unable-to-install-import-tkinter)

but none of them helped.
While trying these solutions, if noticed that the error says:

```
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
```

then i googled about it and found [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).
Reading the **Checking your Tkinter support** section, the `Step 1` failed and was stuck in this line

> If you install Tcl/Tk in the default locations, simply rerunning "make" should build the _tkinter extension.

Regarding above line, my question is:
Where to find a make file to run a `make` command on ?

And, how do I configure the `tkinter` so that Python3.4.2 accepts it ?

---

### EDIT:

I forgot to mention but `import tkinter` do works for the default installation (Python-3.4.0) of the Python in Ubuntu 14.04.1

Comment: Do you really need 3.4.2? I'm asking because tk will still be 8.6 on 14.04

Comment: @SylvainPineau yes, as the [Python Official Site](https://www.python.org) quotes "Python 3.4 includes a range of improvements of the 3.x series, including hundreds of small improvements and bug fixes."

Comment: I've updated my answer to create the `tkinter` module for your 3.4.2 version built from source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to build python3.4.2 from source with the `_tkinter` module you need to install the following build dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev
```

Then all you have to do is running `make` again to add `_tkinter` support as the `setup.py` file will automatically detect the tk/tcl headers and create the module:

```
~/Downloads/Python-3.4.2$ make
running build
running build_ext
building '_tkinter' extension
gcc -pthread -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DWITH_APPINIT=1 -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/X11/include -I./Include -I. -IInclude -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2/Include -I/home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2 -c /home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2/Modules/_tkinter.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2/Modules/_tkinter.o
gcc -pthread -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DWITH_APPINIT=1 -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/X11/include -I./Include -I. -IInclude -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/local/include -I/home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2/Include -I/home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2 -c /home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2/Modules/tkappinit.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2/Modules/tkappinit.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2/Modules/_tkinter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/home/sylvain/Downloads/Python-3.4.2/Modules/tkappinit.o -L/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib -ltk8.6 -ltcl8.6 -lX11 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/_tkinter.cpython-34m.so

Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _dbm                  _gdbm              
_lzma                 _sqlite3                                 
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
[...]
```

Now you can import tkinter in python3.4.2:

```
~/Downloads/Python-3.4.2$ ./python 
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 30 2014, 11:34:17) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

---

**Original answer:**

Unless you really need python3.4.2, I would just use the default python3 version on 14.04 ([3.4.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3))

Then all you have to do is installaling the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk tk
```

And start the python interpreter this way:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

Otherwise you'll always get the version that you installed in `/usr/local` (3.4.2).

Importing tk in python3 should work now:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

Comment: Problem still persists. `tk8.6-dev` dependency is already installed. And that makes a point, if `tk8.6-dev` wouldn't have been  previously installed `tkinter` module wouldn't have worked for Python-3.4.0 either.

Comment: @devGeek Actually you don't need it for 3.4.0. it's only required to build python from source

Comment: Hey, it did work. Runnig, `./python` did work. But, how to make it work using `python3` in the terminal (by default)

Comment: @devGeek to replace your default version with 3.4.2, just run `sudo make install`. It will install 3.4.2 in `/usr/local`. Original 3.4.0 is still available with `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Sure, I already did `sudo make install`. Thanks! BTW the `python3` opens 3.4.2 and for 3.4.0 `python3m` works.

Comment: I'm now facing a new problem due to python3.4 error. See, [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/543904/software-and-updates-in-system-settings-not-working)

Comment: Awesome! I use python environment.  It is nice to see that a simple make and install solved it, no need to make the environment again.

Answer (score 0):

If you need tkinter only for matplotlib, you can also use a different backend, like Egg:
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931376/generating-matplotlib-graphs-without-a-running-x-server/4935945#4935945)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk tk  

pyenv install 3.5.0
```

that's it

Comment: What does this add to the existing, accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.
Adding to the first answer do these things from the python file(After extraction):

```
./configure #(there will be a configure file)
make
make test
sudo make install
```

I had done these things the first time but still it was showing me these errors:

```
IDLE can't import Tkinter.  Your Python may not be configured for Tk.
```

while running `python3 -m idlelib.idle` from cmd.

So I did:

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
```

or you can do

```
sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev
```

then again

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

This solved the issue as the next time I ran 
`python3 -m idlelib.idle`, it opened the IDLE.